# Why can't I see live wallpaper option in HTC wildfire after updating to 2.2 (Froyo)?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-wildfire

Hi I updated my HTC Wildfire from 2.1 to 2.2(Froyo) i can't see an option to set live wallpapers also i don find the Android wallpaper option. Is there any fix available to this.

Answer (score 3):

Live Wallpapers aren't available for the Wildfire.

Comment: hey 
i have a wildfire updated to 2.2 and live wallpapers work just fine on mine :)

Comment: How do you update the wildfire to 2.2?

Comment: Rooting it @Ali, so it allows to install custom roms

Answer (score 1):

Live walls are available for wildfire if you install custom ROM. For example i use WildpuzzleROM. But there are lags while you use some walls. Processro is too slow. You can install custom kernel and increase frequency up to 768MHz.